# Using HIDAPI, how can you query the raw report descriptor?

Tags: hid, hidapi

I'd like to deconstruct the raw reports received from the `hid_read` function of [`hidapi`](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi).

As I understand, this can be achieved using the information from the device's report descriptors. But when trying to query for those descriptors, I get lost somewhere between the HID Spec and using the methods available in `hidapi`.

I would love to see a concrete C or node-hidapi based example that queries and enumerates all the report descriptors for a device — perhaps a mouse to keep things simple?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked Alan Ott by email about this, and he responded with **no** as follows:

> HIDAPI does not provide functions for getting or parsing the report
>   descriptor. Since HIDAPI is for talking to a custom devices, these
>   devices will likely contain all or mostly vendor-defined report items
>   anyway.

Comment: Thanks, this was not really apparent from their docs! I had spend a lot of time trying to understand what is going on =)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it will get the same job done. I highly recommend you use libusbx over any other hid library. If you are willing to do so, [here](https://github.com/libusbx/libusbx/blob/master/examples/listdevs.c) is a very blatant example of device enumeration.

Edit:

It appears that libusbx has been [merged](http://libusbx.org/) back into libusb. This is awesome! As the above link is broken, [here](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/master/examples/listdevs.c) is the new link.

Comment: That looks fantastic — I'll take a deeper dive into it.

Comment: Feel free to check if you like it! :)

Comment: @eatonphil link you posted seems promising, but its broken.Can you repost it.

Comment: @ShaneHolloway did you get through the solution?How about using lsusb -vv in the linux and get the information you desire to get.

Comment: @Raulp, sure thing, just edited my post. Apparently libusbx has been merged back into libusb!

Comment: @eatonphil Can you please explain why you highly recommend using libusb over any other hid library? I would be curious to know what is the reason behind this recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I had success with using both https://github.com/Orochimarufan/HIDRAW/tree/master/HIDRAW_test (that is hopefully the C code example that you asked about) and [RDD! USB HID Report Descriptor Decoder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hidrdd/) for more descriptive output.